# javascript: memory difference of resetting a set variable?

Tags: javascript

Given the code:

```
function foo() {
  if (!this.isValid) {
    this.isValid = true; 
  }
}
```

and if I have `foo()` triggered by an resize event, is it any less efficient to do this:

```
function foo() {
  this.isValid = true; 
}
```

where it would be constantly setting `this.isValid = true` .  The end result is the same but it's just resetting the variable over and over.  Is there a difference memory wise to either one?

Comment: No, but your runtime will be (micro) faster with the second approach.

Comment: oh really?  I would have thought the first approach would be fast since it's only setting the variable once.

Comment: @sal3jfc But it still has to read the variable and check it. Write isn't really less effecient than read.

Comment: maybe second one is better because result will be given quickly as @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans said

Comment: don't worry about micro-optimisations like this. It will literally make no difference in basically 100% of cases. Use the code you think is most readable, and if you hit performance problems, *then* profile to find the slow bits and optimise them. But I'm pretty certain that if you do hit performance problems, this construct won't be responsible.

Comment: What Robin said. Don't micro-optimize until you've literally run out of anything else to do, your code is done, and there is nothing left to improve in terms of actual algorithms and codeflow. This is the kind of optimization you start looking at only when you're at the stage where you're trying find nanosecond improvements: (1) make it work at all, (2) make it work well, (3) make it work well, faster.

Answer (score 0):

There wont be significant difference in both of them. As in the case of `if`, you ll have a comparison added. Incase of direct resetting of the value. you ll skip the comparison but the assignment operator will take up some time.
This can help for a cleaner code

```
function foo() {
   this.isValid = this.isValid || true; 
}
// so you value will not be overwritten
```

Comment: I don't personally find this much cleaner, IMO `this.isValid = true` is OK.

Comment: The only benefit is that it doesnt override the existing value. Rest explanation I have mentioned above

Comment: The only situation where this would be preferable is if `isValid` could have a non-boolean value and you need to preserve it when truthy.